# Match everything until upcase word

Tags: regex, string

I want to capture a word placed before another one which is full capitalized

```
Mister Foo BAR is here        # => "Foo"
Miss Bar-Barz FOO loves cats  # => "Bar-Barz"
```

I've been trying the following regex: `(Mister|Miss)\s([[:alpha:]\s\-]+)(?=\s[A-Z]+)`, but sometimes it includes the rest of the sentence. For example, it'll return `Bar-Barz FOO loves cats` instead of `Bar-Barz`).

- How can I say, using RegExp, "match every words until the upcase word" ?
- To clarify the usage of negative lookahead, can we say it "captures until the specified sub-pattern matches, but does not include it to the match data" ?

As a non-native English speaker, apologies if my answer isn't perfectly formulated. Thanks by advance

Comment: Can you confirm that there won't be people named like "Miss Foo B Bar ETC etc"? Or what I'm trying to say; would the uppercase word always be 2 letters or more?

Comment: You right, every surname consists in at least 4 capitalized characters. Though, some may contains hyphens, as `FOO-BAR`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to capture a word placed before another one which is full capitalized

You may use this regex with a lookahead:

```
\b\S+(?=[ \t]+[A-Z]+\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pIffen/3)

**RegEx Description:**

- `\b`: Word boundadry
- `\S+`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters
- `(?=[ \t]+[A-Z]+\b)`: Positive lookahead that asserts we have 1+ space and then a word containing only capital letters

Comment: Thanks for illustrating the usage of lockahead, it really helps me to understand !

Comment: The fourth bird's answer also fulfills my question, though your expression is more efficient

Answer (score 3):

Match 1+ word chars optionally repeated by a `-` and 1+ word chars to not match only hyphens or a hyphen at the end.

Assert a space followed by 1+ uppercase chars and a word boundary at the right.

```
\w+(?:-\w+)*(?=\s[A-Z]+\b)
```

**Explanation**

- `\w+` Match 1+ word char
- `(?:-\w+)*` Optionally repeat matching `-` and 1+ word chars
- `(?=\s[A-Z]+\b)` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly at the right is 1+ uppercase chars A-Z followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ywZvzk/1)

If there can not be any newlines between the words, you can use `[^\S\r\n]` instead of `\s`

```
\w+(?:-\w+)*(?=[^\S\r\n]+[A-Z]+\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vVmuhm/1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as anubhava's one, a practical use of lockahead was exactly what I need to understand how they work

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what language you're working in, but the following works for me. The idea is to stop when the parser hits a sequence of uppercase letters/hyphens.

JS example:

```
let ptn = /(Mister|Miss)\s[\w\-]+(?=\s[A-Z\-]+)/;
"Mister Foo BAR is here".match(ptn); //["Mister Foo", "Mister"]
"Miss Bar-Barz FOO loves cats".match(ptn); //["Miss Bar-Barz", "Miss"]
```